# Full site not responding to iPad

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug, status-completed

Some icons/areas do not seem to respond to tapping or hovering on iPad. Particularly, the "Stack Exchange" notification on the upper left, and voting up/down,and adding a comment do not seem to respond to touching on an iPad. Is this expected,or is a bug?

Sometimes, once in a while, it works.

Edit. This is caused on the full site with iPad. I do not know with other devices.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. But also sounds like something for the main SO forum (doubt it's particular to the Japanese site).

Comment: @Dave I had a comment to my answer to [this](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/771/can-i-change-the-google-account-that-i-created-my-stack-exchange-username-on) question from SE staff, saying that they monitor all meta sites, so no need to repost on SO :)

Comment: @ジョン: indeed, it might not be necessary to repost. But probably can't hurt to post in the appropriate meta in the first place (even if they do monitor JLU meta, the amount of localised stuff in this group might make general problems go overlooked more easily).

Comment: Probably a little more detail is desirable.  (1) The title says “touch device” but the body is only about iPad.  Are you talking specifically about iPad, or does it also occur on other touch devices?  (2) Is this about the mobile site or about the full site?

Comment: It seems to work OK on the stock browser of my Transformer Prime (Android 4.0.3). I don't have an iPad to test on and it's probably not as functional, but it might be worth trying the mobile site (there's a link to the left of "contact us" in the bottom right corner of every page.)

Comment: Unable to replicate on iPhone 4, iOS 5.1.1 stock (unmodified) Safari. Commenting using that setup right now, in "full site" (not mobile version) SE and everything works including voting, notification button, etc.

Comment: @ジョン I cannot from third generation iPad iOS 5.1.1 I switched to mobile mode, and am commenting now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be with Safari browser used on iPad. Chrome browser on iPad seems to be working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with the full site from iPad. I followed cypher's advice and the mobile site seems to work on iPad. Probably, with smaller touch devices, the site is automatically switched to mobile site and the problem had not arisen. As a work around, I can manually switch to mobile site. So, this seems to be a specific problem for iPad.