# bounty for meta

Tags: feature-request

My question [Full site not responding to iPad](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/805/not-responding-to-a-touch-device) has not been paid much attention by the moderators of stack exchange. I wish there were bounty for meta questions.

Comment: The Stack Exchange admins are probably not interested in increasing their rep points. Therefore, I am not sure how bounties can help receiving more attention from SE admins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a workaround, try posting on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), where it should receive more attention.  Also, since MSO has a full-fledged reputation system of it's own, you can post bounties on that site if your issue doesn't receive a response.

Bounties are supposed to be used to draw attention to issues on meta, not just for rep, but I think the community team has a hard time keeping up with 80+ child meta forums.